# HttpWebRequest returns 404s for 302s only in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, internet-explorer, httpwebrequest

I have a Silverlight (v3) application that uses [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(VS.95).aspx) to make an HTTP POST request to a webpage on the same website as the Silverlight app. This HTTP request gets back a 302 (a redirect) to another page on the same website, which [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28VS.95%29.aspx) is automatically supposed to follow ([according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect%28VS.95%29.aspx)).

There's nothing particularly special about the code that makes the request (it uses the browser's HTTP stack, it is not configured to use the alternate inbuilt Silverlight HTTP stack):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}?name={1}&size={2}", _UploadUrl, Uri.EscapeUriString(Name), TotalBytes));
request.Method = "POST";
```

All this works fine in Firefox and Chrome; Silverlight makes the POST HTTP request, receives a 302 response and automatically does a GET HTTP request of the specified redirect URL and returns that to me (I know this because I used Fiddler to watch the HTTP requests going on). 
However, in Internet Explorer (v8), Silverlight does the POST HTTP request and then throws a WebException with a 404 error code!

Using Fiddler, I can see that Silverlight/Internet Explorer was successfully returned the 302 status code for the request, and I assume that the 404 status code (and associated WebException) that I get in Silverlight is because as far as I know HTTP requests that are done via the browser stack can only return 200 or 404 due to limitations. The real question is **why does Internet Explorer not follow through the redirect like the other browsers**?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:** I would prefer not to use the Silverlight client HTTP stack because to my knowledge requests issued by it do not include cookies that are a part of the browser's session, critically including the ASP.NET authentication cookie that I need to be attached to the HTTP requests being made by the Silverlight control.

**EDIT 2:** I have discovered that Internet Explorer only exhibits this behaviour when you do a POST request. A GET request redirects successfully. This seems like pretty bad behaviour considering how many websites now do things in the Post-Redirect-Get style.

Comment: The redirected url also pointing at a resource in the same server that was POSTed to and that the Xap came from?

Comment: As far I know, Chrome and Firefox may handle credentials differently. Is there something about credentials ? Is the requested URL accept anonymous or authenticated requests ? Did you check the server access logs for HTTP Codes ?

Comment: Can you use the client HTTP handling facility? That way you will get access to all status codes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Yes. I've edited and clarified this in the question now. 

@JoeBilly: Both the originally requested and redirected to URLs require ASP.NET Forms Authentication. Using Fiddler and a debugger attached to the ASP.NET website I can see that authentication is working fine; IE (and the other browsers) are including the forms auth cookie with the request and the server accepts it.

@Feroze: I'd like to avoid the client HTTP stack for reasons I've edited into the question above.

Comment: Are the HTTP headers alike ? Especially caching headers ? About the 404 error which probably hide the real response : try to get the real response from WebException.Response.

Comment: @JoeBilly: WebException.Response returns a stub object on which basically nothing is set except the 404 status code. It's not a caching problem. Fiddler shows the request actually happening (and it's not a HEAD request) and the response is the expected redirect. Either way it doesn't work in my new demo app either, which hasn't given IE the chance to cache anything that would cause this sort of behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

IE is closer to the specification, in that in responding to a 302 for a POST the user agent should send a POST (though it should not do so without user confirmation).

On the other hand, FF and Chrome are deliberately wrong, in copying ways in which user agents were frequently wrong some considerable time ago (the problem started in the early days of HTTP).

For this reason, 307 was introduced in HTTP/1.1 to be clearer that the same HTTP method should be used (i.e. in this case, it should be a POST) while 303 has always meant that one should use GET.

Therefore, instead of doing `Response.Redirect` which results in a 302 - that different user agents will handle in different ways, send a 303. The following code does so (and includes a valid entity body just to be within the letter of the spec). There is an overload so you can call it with either a Uri or a string:

```
private void SeeOther(Uri uri)
{
  if(!uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
    uri = new Uri(Request.Url, uri);
  Response.StatusCode = 303;
  Response.AddHeader("Location", uri.AbsoluteUri);
  Response.ContentType = "text/uri-list";
  Response.Write(uri.AbsoluteUri);
  Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
private void SeeOther(string relUri)
{
  SeeOther(new Uri(Request.Url, relUri));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I tried changing the redirect to a 303 (as well as the other things in your sample code above), however Internet Explorer continues to return a 404 to my Silverlight control's request regardless. :( (Apologies for the late reply)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was a feature change in Internet Explorer 7, where by they changed the expected 200 response to a 302 telling IE to be redirected. There is no smooth solution to this problem that I know off. A similar question was posed a while back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398068/ie-302-redirect-no-cache-header-problem).

[Change in behavior with Internet Explorer 7 and later in regard to CONNECT requests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/06/18/change-in-behavior-with-internet-explorer-7-and-later-in-regard-to-connect-requests.aspx)

Comment: I don't think my issue is related to this. The blog post you linked clearly says that that behaviour is for CONNECT requests (ie HTTPS), which I am not doing; my requests are all done with normal HTTP.